# Show Div and hide others with A Href onclick

Tags: jquery, html, href

I have a menu with some links. Like this:

```
<ul id="nav"><li><a href="#" class="tartalom">Some Div 1</a></li><li><a href="#" class="tartalom2">Some Div 2</a></li></ul>
```

Here are my divs.

```
  <div class="tartalom1>Bla bla bla</div> 

  <div class="tartalom2>Yeeah yeah yeah</div>
```

How to make it possible, if I click on the links to open that div with the same class and close the others if they are open? I tried this, but it wont help:

```
   $(document).ready( function(){
  $('.tartalom').click( function(){ // set of divs to be clickable
   $(this).siblings('div').hide(); // it's already showing, right?
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reach the enclosing div first to access siblings divs. You can use [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function to find the nearest ancestor matching the search criteria.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/c4mJC/)**

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('.tartalom').click( function(){ // set of divs to be clickable
      $(this).closest('div').siblings('div').hide(); // it's already showing, right?
  });
});
```

You also **missed** the closing quotes of `tartalom1` and `tartalo2` class in divs.

Comment: Sorry, but i want to open the divs and close the others, so not just close the others :)

Comment: Can you expalain what behaviour you are trying to achieve?